# Apps rejecting every times

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I am updating my aaps to aap store but it's getting rejected every time.

Actually I am developing this app for schools with multiple branches, and every branch of school required same app icon but with different app name. Every branch has different server link as well as database on different server.

**The Review team reply me -**

**We noticed that your app provides the same feature set as many of the other apps you've submitted to the App Store; it simply varies in content or language.**

**To resolve this issue, please combine apps with similar feature sets into a single "container" app (using the in-app purchase API to deliver different content if appropriate).**

Comment: No one can help except apple.And they have guided you clearly..If you are still unclear request a call with them and you can get the solution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the AppStore approval process (compare https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic)

Comment: iDeveloper, I have same problem. Has there been any progress on this issue?

Comment: @andrei200287 I have make a single app, for all the schools. I am just enter the school code at splash view, and app work according to that school.

Comment: @iDeveloper , what did you name your app now after combining all your apps into single, i am also facing the same problem. what if the school wants branded app for with its name on app store?

Comment: @DhanunjayKumar, I am using my company name, After that, I can enter school code and that school will be open according to the school code. You Can also set name your app as The School or etc. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies with the architecture of the application. 
An iOS App cannot be launched like a solution software in web, where someone develops it and multiple versions of it is available under different domain or different organisation.

A safe bet would be apple wont entertain your any request as these are published app. You may argue that the app is for this specific people, then You should have NOT launched the app in app store, rather made the application an **Enterprise** application.

Or if your moto is to launch the app in App store , then you should follow the following architecture, where there would have been only 1 application, but servers maybe different which is controlled by a single API call in the beginning  which will determine the rest of the calls in which server according to any other parameter by you. Then a simple login or any other feature which would enable users to select the organisation they would want to connect with (in case here, school)

Releasing an application in App store, means its available to the store of that country to everyone and apple is giving you a reply that you have launched similar applications before. You can launch an appeal but I would suggest release the app in ERP mode via testflight or any other distribution software.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You may try to give this explanation to Apple and see what they have to say.

If they do not understand you try to see if this works

1. Put the name of the branch in the icon (this will help user identify)
2. Also add the name of branch at the if the app name

If this doesn't works you will have to publish in different developer account or else you will have to combine all the apps and user will get option of branch in app when they enter app for the first time.

Do let me know if this works.

Comment: I am already appeal to Apple, but they reply **- We encourage you to review your app concept and incorporate different content and features that are in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.**

Comment: I mean they rejecting apps every time.

Comment: When it comes to review from Apple it varies from case to case. They rejected on my app for 7 times and I kept submitting giving them explanation lately we had a call over a phone and they approve the app in no less then 10 mins. You would have explain them properly and give some valid reason behind it and see what can happen. I have a contact details of the reviewer who approved my app but I am not sure if that will be of help. You can also try to call Apple and see if they have anything to say if you don't have to merge the app you will have to explain them.

Comment: Sounds good @Rajesh

Comment: @iDeveloper try this if this doesn't works using then we have 2 options left as I mentioned above using different developer account and merging the app